How to combine multiple @staticmethod decorators into a single one
I want to combine multiple @statimethod decorators (let's call them decorator_1, decorator_2, etc.) into a single @staticmethod combined_decorator.
For my use case, I need the decorators to be able to access the class object, so I cannot declare my decorators outside the class. Think for example a class exception counter decorator, that would increment a self.exception_count variable whenever the decorated method my_func(self) raises an exception. For example:
import functools

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.exception_count = 0

    @staticmethod
    def count_exception(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"caught: {e}")
                self.exception_count += 1
        
        return wrapper

    @count_exception
    def foo(self):
        raise RuntimeError("exception!")

x = Example()
# prints: "exception count: 0"
print(f"exception count: {x.exception_count}")
x.foo()
x.foo()
# prints: "exception count: 2"
print(f"exception count: {x.exception_count}")

In this toy example, there is only a single decorator and a single decorator methods. In my case, I have many decorators, many decorated methods, and always using the same decoration pattern. So instead of writing:
    @decorator_1
    @decorator_2
    # ...
    @decorator_X
    def foo():
        pass

I would to have a single @combined_decorator.
I have tried the following implementation, which does not work:
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def _decorator1(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("static decorator 1")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    def _decorator2(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("static decorator 2")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
        
    @staticmethod
    def _combined_decorator(func):
        
        @MyClass._decorator1
        @MyClass._decorator2
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    @_combined_decorator
    def my_func(self):
        print("my func")

x = MyClass()
x.my_func()

The issue here is NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined inside the definition of _combined_decorator
I have several variants: using @classmethod, changing @MyClass._decoratorX to @_decoratorX, etc. But nothing seems to work.
I am using 3.10, so I think it should be possible for @staticmethod to call other @staticmethod within the same class, which is as far as I understand all that should be required.
Any idea?

A class is only defined after the closing brace of its declaration. That means that you cannot use it inside the definition of the class. But when you say: I need the decorators to be able to access the class object, so I cannot declare my decorators outside the class, you are wrong. You should give a example of what you want to get access from the decorator.

... Anyway the way you define your decorator is plain wrong. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

@SergeBallesta sorry if my example was not very clear. I have updated the example to make it clearer.

Will the decorators also be used independently on some methods, or will they always be used as _combined_decorator? If its the latter, is there any reason you can't just write the functionality you need as a single decorator?

just don't, define the decorators outside the class

as an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions, if only to get more eyeballs on your question!

@nigh_anxiety it would mean writing a frankenstein decorator. For the sake of simplicity I only mentionned a single combined decorator, but eventually I would like to define multiples.

@juanpa.arrivillaga That's also something I have been thinking about, but I cannot find any elegant solution. For example, how would you write the count_exception example?

@juanpa.arrivillaga Now I try it out. I realize it is not a problem at all. The decorator can be moved outside and still modify the class object internals. Type annotation seems to work just fine aswell.

If you prefer to organize the decorators in the same namespace of the class as where they are used, you can create a factory function that dynamically produces a decorator that returns the decorated function with all the given decorators iteratively applied. This works because the factory function can be called with the decorators in the same namespace as arguments. Keep in mind that the inner decorators are applied first so the decorators should be passed in the reverse order of their original appearance:
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    def _decorator1(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("static decorator 1")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    def _decorator2(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("static decorator 2")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod        
    def _combine_decorators(*decorators):
        def decorator(func):
            for decorator in decorators:
                func = decorator(func)
            return func
        return decorator

    _combined_decorator = _combine_decorators(_decorator2, _decorator1)

    @_combined_decorator
    def my_func(self):
        print("my func")

x = MyClass()
x.my_func()

This outputs:
static decorator 1
static decorator 2
my func

Demo here

Short answer:
The simplest workaround is to move the decorators outside the class as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested. No more @staticmethod, no more issue.
If I really want to keep things inside the class definition, another workaround is to move the decorator into an inner layer to get self and call @self.decorator_X, like so:
    @staticmethod
    def _combined_decorator(func):
        
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):

            @self._decorator1
            @self._decorator2
            def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

            return inner(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

One downside is that a new decorated function is generated on each function call. This could lead to strange side effects.
One last solution is to keep the decorator definition inside the class, but to move the decoration after the class definition, as shown below.
Long answer:
The issue with my initial implementation comes from the fact that while @staticmethod methods can refer to other static methods at runtime, it does not work for @ decoration simply because such decorated functions are evaluated during class definition (so the class object is not defined yet). This becomes clearer when you think about @my_decorator being just syntactic sugar for this:
class Test: 
    @staticmethod
    def my_decorator(func):
        pass

    def my_func(self):
        pass
    my_func = my_decorator(my_func)

While python allows you to call my_decorator within the class body, the class Test does not exists yet so my_decorator would not be able to call Test.my_other_decorator.
One thing I don't understand however, is that you can write my_func = my_decorator(my_func) or my_other_func = my_other_decorator(my_other_func), but my_decorator cannot call my_other_decorator.
Admitting this limitation, another (ugly) workaround is to add the decoration outside the class, as shown below:
class Test:
    
    @staticmethod
    def direct_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("direct_decorator")
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    def indirect_decorator(func):
        return Test.direct_decorator(func)

    """ Same as:
        def hello_direct(self):
            print("hello_direct")
        hello_direct = direct_decorator(hello_direct)
    """
    @direct_decorator
    def hello_direct(self):
        print("hello_direct")

    # @indirect_decorator   # does not work
    def hello_indirect(self):
        print("hello_indirect")

# Test is defined, so not problem here
Test.hello_indirect = Test.indirect_decorator(Test.hello_indirect)

x = Test()
x.hello_direct()
x.hello_indirect()


" but my_decorator cannot call my_other_decorator." because you are defining the decorators in the class scope and class scopes don't form enclosing scopes. That's why you have to write self.other_method() in some method!
